# Creating new layer with points from selection in different shape on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm importing a shapefile with an attribute table with Lat/Lon for each point.

Is there a way to create a new layer with the coordinates from this shape as points?

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial describes well how to do it: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html

Summarized:

- go to layer > add layer > add delimited text layer
- pick your file and set X- and Y-field